# R-Studio - computing crosstab and creating a table

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to programming and R. My R experience thus far has been Udemy's courses; specifically the Beginner and Intermediate R courses.

My data analysis background is heavily Excel and SPSS, as such I am trying to carry over those skills and find applicable analysis strategies in R.

I am attempting to compute a crosstabs, which will output the frequencies for the sets of 'character' data I am analyzing.

Below is a piece of code I am used to create a crosstab:

**crosstab(Survey, row.vars = c("testcode","outcome"), col.vars = "svy1", type = "j")**

I am able to see the data output in the Console, but I am unable to move it/put it into its own matrix like table in the Environment; the purpose being to create matrix like tables for reporting. I am sure there is an easy fix I am overlooking but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO and to R. You can assign the result of the call to an object using `my_tab <- crosstab(...`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should always include a small sample data set example with your question, so we can try to replicate the problem/solution.

Comment: HubertL, in this case, inserting the resulting output into an object returns a list, whereas I want a data frame like matrix.  One thing I should mention is that the data was imported from a CSV so it is already in a dataframe/matrix.  pyll, below is a visual of how the data is arranged. Essentially nestled by testcode, then outcome, and then the frequencies within those filtered parameters

Comment: This is essentially where I collected all information about crosstabs... http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html